# Zend Framework application.ini Router problems

Tags: zend-framework

OK, I'm pretty new to this, and ploughing through all the tutorials and answered questions I can find. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a complete application.ini that works for me.

Somewhere I must have stuffed up - I can get the basic routing working OK, but as soon as I try and add a variable I can't get it to work. So /guide-to works, but /guide-to/london gives the error "someplace is not specified"

I'm doing all the routing in application.ini. Here's my file:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/layouts/"
resources.layout.layout = wrapper

resources.view = ""

resources.router.routes.home.route = "/stuff"
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.controller = index
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.action = index 

resources.router.routes.guide-to.route = "/guide-to"
resources.router.routes.guide-to.defaults.controller = "destination"
resources.router.routes.guide-to.defaults.action = "guide-to" 

resources.router.routes.place.route = "guide-to/:someplace"
resources.router.routes.place.defaults.controller = "destination"
resources.router.routes.place.defaults.action = "guide-to" 

resources.router.routes.guides.route = "/guiderrrs"
resources.router.routes.guides.defaults.controller = destination
resources.router.routes.guides.defaults.action = guiderrrs

resources.router.routes.guidez.route = "/guidez"
resources.router.routes.guidez.defaults.controller = destination
resources.router.routes.guidez.defaults.action = guidez 

pagination.item.count.per.page = 10

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Can anyone spot the problem? Or does anyone have a working application.ini they could share?

All contributions gratefully received!

Comment: one thing to keep in mind with routes "Routes are matched in reverse order so make sure your most generic routes are defined first". I don't think this is your issue, but I'm not sure as I'm not sure if the top route is first or last :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a default value for someplace variable. someplace is variable so you need to give it a default value.  Otherwise it will default to undefine.
I think like this :

```
resources.router.routes.place.defaults.someplace="deault_value"
```

In my opinion it's not a good idea to map your url to the exact names.
because url becomes really coupled with the application wich can change.

I rather prefer to use a generic router in my bootstrap.  and then map my url to it. using this approach my routing system is the same as I start a new project.
Use seomthing like this in your bootstrap . it is even shorter than defining all the routes 
because if things change you would need to change back

```
protected function _initRoutes(){
    $front_controller=self::getFrontController();
    $router =  $front_controller->getRouter();

    $standard_route=new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':lang/:module/:controller/:action/:param_one/:param_two/:param_three/*',
        array(  'lang'=>$user_language,
                'module'=>'default',
                'controller'=>'index',
                'action' => 'index',
                'param_one'=>NULL,
                'param_two'=>NULL,
                'param_three'=>NULL
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('standard', $standard_route);


    $default_route=new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':lang/:controller/:action/:param_one/:param_two/:param_three/*',
        array( 'lang'=>$user_language,
               'module'=>'default',
               'controller'=>'index',
               'action' => 'index',
               'param_one'=>NULL,
               'param_two'=>NULL,
               'param_three'=>NULL
        )
    );      
    $router->addRoute('default', $default_route);


    $front_controller->setRouter($router);


}
```

Lang is my own variable for internationalization suppor.

Comment: That work or me Evan - fantastic job! I had to change just one bit - added a defaults - but now I'm back on track!  resources.router.routes.defaults.place.someplace="deault_value"

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is correct. I believe you are using the parameter wrong judging by the error.

You should have a controller in your default module called DestinationController and have this as a minimum to get access to your someplace variable.

```
class DestinationController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function guideToAction()
    {
        var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParams());
        var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParam('someplace'));
        exit;
    }
}
```

This works for me with the config you have given.

Hope it helps.